# insufficient access rights on cross-reference id in Flow when Writing to Lookup Field

Tags: permissions

I have a lookup field to the account on a custom object. I have a flow that I'm using to populate fields to that object that is used by our community users. When I try to write to the account lookup, I'm receiving a "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" error when using the community user, but have no issues when debugging as the admin. Any ideas on which permissions would prevent me from writing an ID to the account lookup?

Comment: Whats FLS for account for Community Profile

Answer (score 0):

Does your community profile has the right access i.e view access for the account object.

For admin all the access are already there, so no issues when running the same thing as admin.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Hi Tushar, SFSE etiquette tends to avoid lines such as `Please mark the answer if this solves your ask.`